# Most efficient way of having an object move across a video?

Tags: flash, editing, video-editing, adobe-premiere

I have a still image that I would like to utilize to move across a `.wmv` file I have. What is the easiest and most proficient way I can accomplish this without having to go frame by frame? I wasn't sure if there was an easy way to do this in Premiere or if Flash should be used?